# Values in the model lost in the controller after postback

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I am unable to getthe values in the of the selected dropdown box after selecting them from the view and doing a postback. My code is as follows

Code in the model

```
public class SeleniumModel
    {
        public SeleniumModel()
        {
            BrowserList = new List<SelectListItem>();
            EnviormentList = new List<SelectListItem>();
        }


        public List<SelectListItem> BrowserList
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public List<SelectListItem> EnviormentList
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
  }
```

COde in the controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            SeleniumModel model = new SeleniumModel();
            model.BrowserList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Internet Explorer", Value = "ie" });
            model.BrowserList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "FireFox", Value = "firefox" });
            model.BrowserList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Chrome", Value = "chrome" });

            model.EnviormentList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Local", Value = "ie" });
            model.EnviormentList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Dev", Value = "dev" });
            model.EnviormentList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Uat", Value = "uat" });


            return View("Index", model);
        }
```

Code in the view

```
<div class="fields">
                <div>
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Browser)
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model =>  model.BrowserList,Model.BrowserList)
                </div>
            </div>

                <div class="fields">
                <div>
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Enviornment)
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model =>  model.EnviormentList,Model.EnviormentList)
                </div>
```

Comment: You need separate properties in your model to bind to - `public string SelectedBrowser { get; set; }` and `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedBrowser, Model.BrowserList)`

Comment: It appears from your view that you already have a property named `Browser` (use in the label) so that probably what you want to bind to

Comment: As @Stephen Muecke commented, bind your `Browser` property to the selected item: `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Browser, Model.BrowserList)`. Do exatcly the same for`Environment`.

Answer (score 0):

you may have to revise your SeleniumModel to accomodate the selected Browser you need

```
        public SeleniumModel()
        {
            SelectedBrowser = "";
            BrowserList = new List<SelectListItem>();
            EnviormentList = new List<SelectListItem>();
        }

        public String SelectedBrowser
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public List<SelectListItem> BrowserList
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public List<SelectListItem> EnviormentList
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
```

In your View, try something like this

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedBrowser, Model.BrowserList)
```

When your Controller accepts the Model from the View, you will be able to get the selected Browser using the SelectedBrowser property of your model.